# placing title on top and left side of the plot using facet_wrap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]df

```
Date       Team    Country   Score
1/1/2012   TeamA   Germany  10
1/2/2012   TeamA   Germany  25
1/3/2012   TeamA   Germany  50
1/1/2012   TeamB   France  10
1/2/2012   TeamB   France  70
1/3/2012   TeamB   France  50
```

I would like to create facet wrap graph with ggplot to have title and also put country on the left side of each plot as shown on the image. Is this doable with ggplot?

```
ggplot(df,aes(Date, Score, group=Team, colour=Team))+ 
        geom_point(size=0.5) + 
        geom_smooth(method="lm", se=T, size=1) + 
        facet_wrap(~Team, scale="free")
```

### [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define

```
dat.text
   Team Country x  y
3 TeamA Germany 3 30
4 TeamB  France 3 15
```

Using geom_text

```
 p + geom_text(aes(x, y, label=Country, group=NULL),data=dat.text,
               angle =90,family = "mono",size=12)
    + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

The idea: I use  a new data frame with three pieces of information and suuply it to geom_text.

ggplot do the rest of job.

- Coordinates (x,y)
- The faceted variable levels : Team
- The labels to be supplied   : Country

  To put the text in the right of plot , I choose

  ```
   dat.text$x  <- tail(originalData$Date,1)
  ```

Comment: this is not what I am looking for. My question is, using facet_wrap, is it possible to put the title in the right side of the plot?

Comment: Ah oki! but Your plot is little confusing! but, if you get what this ,  the idea is the same..prepare the data ...and ggplot do the rest..